# AQH3223 vs AQH3213

Tags: relay

I would like to know what the difference between the [AQH3223](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/relays-contactors/semiconductor-relays/solid-state/series/82437/model/82512) relay and the [AQH3213](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/relays-contactors/semiconductor-relays/series/82437/model/82508) is?
I know the AQH3213 is zero-cross, but I would like to understand for sure what that is.

Can I use one of these relays to control a DC output?

The circuit I want to do, consists of activating a relay output through a 24v signal.
Image below

I put the input connected to an optocoupler, and then the signal goes through the BC547 transistor. That after the switch is pressed (signal arrives at the optoacploador), activates an output through the relay. Output that I wanted to give as much to DC as AC
[image]

Comment: Zero-crossing relays like AQH3213 switch on when the output voltage passes close to zero and always switch off at zero current. You can use it for switching resistive or capacitive loads.
Random relays like AQH3223 have the output turn on as soon as voltage is applied to the input and turn off as soon as the voltage is removed.

Comment: @RafaelFreitas - Hi, Since another site member has added links to the product pages for the relays, I have removed my earlier comment. Please still review the [tour] & [help] for further site rules & info. Also I see you attempted to respond to a comment from another site member, but you did not use the `@username` notification syntax, so (unless they followed this question) they will not be notified of your response (just writing their username does not trigger notifications). For the future, please read [here](/help/privileges/comment) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).

Comment: Thanks @Alinik.
My second question that I still don't know the answer to is, can I use one of these relays in DC circuits? I've already tested it on AC output and it works. I tested it in DC at the output and it doesn't work, after pressing a button (activate the coil), the led turns on, but then it doesn't turn off, it's always on, it only turns off if the power is turned off or if a decoupling capacitor is inserted